# Persisting unstructured data to hadoop using spark streaming

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I have an ingest pipeline created using spark streaming, and I would like to store the RDDs in hadoop as a large unstructured (JSONL) datafile to simplify future analysis.

What is the best approach for persisting astream to hadoop without ending up with very large numbers of small files? (since hadoop is not good with those, and they complicate analysis workflows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest using a persistance layer that can handle this like Cassandra. But, if you are deadset on HDFS, then [the mailing list has an answer already](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/save-spark-streaming-output-to-single-file-on-hdfs-td21124.html)

You can use `FileUtil.copyMerge` (from the hadoop fs) API and specify the path to the folder where `saveAsTextFiles` is saving the part text file.
Suppose your directory is /a/b/c/ use

```
FileUtil.copyMerge(FileSystem of source, a/b/c, 
    FileSystem of destination, Path to the merged file say (a/b/c.txt), 
    true(to delete the original dir,null))
```